# 'Ambiguous Nuts' or 'To Shell or not to Shell'

Tags: adjectives, ambiguity

How does one remove the ambiguity of shelled peanuts? Must one just not use the adjective 'shelled' in relation to peanuts, or other nuts, or shellfish?

Comment: Please edit your question and state explicitly what ambiguity you refer to, and spell out what rationale you are thinking of for not using the adjective *shelled* in that context

Comment: @Susan There's also the past tense v participle adjective ambiguity, though probably only sentence fragments would trigger this: 'Shelled peanuts? _For a living?_"

Answer (score 3):

The usual way people refer to peanuts still in their 'pods' is 'peanuts in their shells' or by using the shorter idiom peanuts 'in the shell'. (idiom because 'the' is pressed into service with a non-specific member of the set of all peanut shells; 'in the flesh' is a more opaque but similar idiom, whereas we don't use say 'in the peel')

'Shelled' is almost always used to mean 'removed from their shells' when referring to nuts at the point of selling / serving / nibbling. *But not in biology.*

I'd say that the usual way to refer to 'extracted' oysters is 'shucked'. Crab is often taken out of the shell, arranged nicely, and put back neatly into the opened-up shell to serve; this is known as 'dressed' crab.

Comment: I ask because I saw a newspaper article back in 1999 in Virginia (that I can't find!) that spoke of a man falling in to a container of "unshelled peanuts". We (the Radiomen of the USS Lasalle) debated whether those peanuts were in or out of the shell. There were more than two schools of thought.